# Flutter, Wrap, remove spacing for conditional widgets

Tags: flutter, spacing

I'm using the widget Wrap this way:

```
Wrap(
  crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
  spacing: 5,
  children: [
    condition1 ? Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.blue) : SizedBox(),
    condition2 ? Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.red) : SizedBox(),
    condition3 ? Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.green) : SizedBox()
  ]
)
```

How can I apply the spacing only on the Container and not on the SizedBox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `SizedBox` is only there as a placeholder and is not useful in any other way, you don't need it at all. Check out alternative syntax:

```
Wrap(
        crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.center,
        spacing: 5,
        children: [
          if (condition1) Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.blue),
          if (condition2) Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.red),
          if (condition3) Container(width: 50, height: 50, color: Colors.green),
        ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap Padding on Container widget